# How do you decide where to go in Amnesia: Dark Descent?

Tags: amnesia-the-dark-descent

Do we need to refer to any kind of guide for this game? I think I'm still at the first level and I have somehow reached the wine cellar. I've been wondering around aimlessly but can't figure out where to go.

So I checked the walkthrough and it appears I had to do a ton of other things before I have to go to the Wine cellar.

How do I figure out where to go? Is there any brief area guide that I can use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an excellent cheat guide bundled along with the game. Go to the game folder and look for the file `super_secret.rar`. Enter the [password](https://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/978772-amnesia-the-dark-descent/cheats) and inside you'll find some design docs for all 3 chapters which includes maps and more information.

One of those image files also contains a flowchart of the order in which you need to visit the areas.

Comment: If you don't want to spoil it for yourself, just try to remember the way till where you entered the current area as well as the area before that. If your not good at recognizing whether you visited an area or not, then indeed map information is a great thing to check out...

Comment: The password is `lke271tyr299odn314`, combined from the strings you receive with each of the three endings. Use a program such as 7-zip to open.

Answer (score 0):

I usually check every corner and wall for levers or doors because the game is really dark sometimes.